# Infinite loop with MSAL library React sample

Tags: reactjs, loops, azure-ad-msal, infinite

I am trying to login user seamlessly, with out having a login button as it will be hosted on Azure. But ending in infinite loop with error:

```
interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress. 
Please ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an interactive API.  
For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.
```

Sample Pagelayout code modified Typescript sample from https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js:

```
export const PageLayout = (props: any) => {
    const { instance,accounts,inProgress } = useMsal();
    if(instance.getActiveAccount() == null)
    {
        console.log('account =' + instance.getActiveAccount());
        instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
    }
    console.log('count =' + instance.getAllAccounts().length);
    console.log('active =' + instance.getAllAccounts());
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">MS Identity Platform</a>
                {/* <SignInSignOutButton/> */}
            </Navbar>
            <h5 className="sample-header">Welcome to the Microsoft Authentication Library For Typescript - React Quickstart</h5>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is addressed here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3667

The suggestion is to  use the [useMsalAuthentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/hooks.md#usemsalauthentication-hook) hook or [MsalAuthenticationTemplate component](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md#msalauthenticationtemplate-component) to achieve auto login on page load.  You can use this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/typescript-sample/src/pages/Profile.tsx) as a guide.